# Attempting to find where my internet data is being used. Does this seem right?

Tags: internet, internet-connection, google-chrome-extensions, bandwidth

Google chrome Extensions Used:

- Adblock Plus
- IDM Integrated
- LastPass
- Neater Bookmarks
- Pocket

I use a monitoring software called "NetWorx" to check the overall internet 
data usage. I also use "Netbalancer" by Seriousbit to check the internet data 
used by each application.

Whenever I google any content, approximately 1MB of internet data is 
being used, as shown by NetWorx. If a Youtube video [length-3:00 mins,320p] is being played, almost 50MB internet data is being used.

Is this Normal?

I Use Avast and Bitdefender, and no virus or spyware is being detected. Do Chrome 
extensions have anything to do with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does NetWorx record the specific URLs that are associated with this bandwidth? If not, try monitoring it with Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) -- knowing what request retrieves that MB will probably help figure out what's doing it.

Comment: @CalvinFisher I tried monitoring with fiddler2 and everything seemed to be normal.NetWorx still shows the same problem.I'm a little skeptical about the plugins,especially Pocket or Adblock Plus.Do you think adblock might be using some internet data as it tries to avoid the adds?fiddler2 doesn't show any adblock useage.